# How to remove inexplicable padding in table cell caused by padding in child div?

Tags: html, css

Check out this fiddle to see a demo of the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/rV6Jg/

All padding on table cells is removed, and `border-collapse` is set to `collapse` on the `<table>` element. The bottom row contains a single cell, which in turn contains a `<div>` that has padding set. This padding somehow causes padding not only on the `<div>` but it's parent cell. When I remove the padding on the child `<div>`, the padding on the parent cell disappears.

Here's the source code for reference

HTML:

```
<div class='wrapper'>
  <table class='table' border=1>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Toolbar stuff goes here...
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class='boxWrapper'>
          <div class='box'>Content stuff goes here...</div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html,body{padding:0px;margin:0px;height:100%;}
.wrapper{
  padding:1em;
  height:100%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.table{
  border-collapse:collapse;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.table td{
  padding:0px !important;
}
.table tr:last-child{
  height:100%;
}
.boxWrapper{
  padding:1em;
  height:100%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.box{
  box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 5px #ccc;
  padding:1em;
  height:100%;
}
```

**UPDATE**

It seems I did not make it clear that I want padding on the `<div>`s inside the , but not on the `<td>` itself, which as you can see from the following screenshot, does indeed have padding (in green):

[image: inexplicable padding on td element]

**UPDATE 2**

Setting `box-sizing:border-box` on `.box` doesn't solve the problem as suggested in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rV6Jg/4/)

[image]

Comment: Isn't the padding coming from the padding you set on `<div class='boxWrapper'>`?

Comment: You have two divs who have paddings inside the td. What don't you understand here?

Comment: Is this what you're after? http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/rV6Jg/3/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set the vertical alignment on your table cells;

```
.table td{
    padding:0px !important;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/rV6Jg/3/)**

Update (2018-07-16): setting `box-sizing: border-box;` on `.box` fixes the issue in Chrome.

Comment: While this is the best answer available, I realized that it still leaves inexplicable spacing at the bottom of the `<td>`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a hard time understanding exactly what it is you're trying to do, but if you [change `padding` to `margin`](http://jsfiddle.net/G3Qf3/) the extra space around the cell is no longer present.

Comment: Yes, I noticed this as well, but margin doesn't play nice with 100% height.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I got something wrong, but to me it looks as if you actually define that padding yourself for the wrapper. You have specified that padding of 1em *twice* in your css, once for the div and once for its wrapper:

```
.boxWrapper{
  padding:1em;
  height:100%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.box{
  box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 5px #ccc;
  padding:1em;
  height:100%;
}
```

If I remove one of them (or both) in the fiddler you provide then I get exactly the behavior one would expect...

Comment: There should be padding on both of these divs, but not their parent <td> element, which is what I'm getting in Chrome 34

Comment: That is not really a padding. This is the result of your 100% height definitions. Note that when you define a height of 100% (relative to the parent element), then the child element _overlaps_ the parent element _if that has a padding defined_. So the content of the table cell requires more space than its child div (the wrapper). Have a try playing around with the 100% settings whilst observing the computed measurements for the elements inside your browsers debug console. It also helps to define a background color for the divs, it helps visualizing what space an element actually requires.

Comment: "if **that** has a padding defined" -- does *that* refer to the child or the parent?  As I understand it, a child element with box-sizing set to border-box should not overlap because of padding; also, if I'm not mistaken, the height of a parent element with padding set, does not include the padding.  Perhaps I misunderstood your comment.

Answer (score 0):

just add `box-sizing: border-box;` to `.box` as well

Comment: That fiddle still contains inexplicable padding (see updated and screenshot in the question).